# Replace Duplicate With Nulls

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following problem.

Suppose I have two tables

Table1

```
MenuItem  Active   Module  MenuItemCode
---------------------------------------
HotDog       Y      FOOD    1000
COKE CAN     N      FOOD    1001
Veggie       Y      FOOD    1002
```

Table2

```
MenuItemCode  Ingredient   Quantity  Price
------------------------------------------
1000           HotDogBun     2       1.00
1000           Hotdog Temp   1       1.00
```

I have used the below query, but not get the expected result.

```
Select T1.MenuItem,T1.Module,T2.Ingredient,T2.Quantity,T2.Price
From 
Table1 T1, Table2 T2 
Where T1.MenuItemCode=T2.MenuItemCode
```

I want a result like below

```
MenuItem  Module  Ingredient   Quantity   Price
------------------------------------------------
HotDog     FOOD   HotDogBun     2         1.00
NULL       NULL   Hotdog Temp   1         1.00
```

Which join I should use to get above expected results.
Kindly help me.

Comment: Why do you want `NULL` instead of the values from `Table1`? Regardless, it's probably easier to deal with this in your application layer.

Comment: The joins you are using were taught in colleges and universities in the '80s and '90s They have been superseded over 20 years ago.

Comment: Alternatively - don't use [old style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Note that when asking a question, it usually helps to specifically state what is wrong with your current answer (e.g., you want only the first row for any MenuItem to have its menuitem and module shown). Of course, in this case, most people would work it out.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want:

```
select t1.MenuItem, t1.Module, t2.Ingredient, t2.Quantity, t2.Price
from table2 t2 left join
     (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by MenuItemCode order by qty desc) as seqnum
      from table1 t1
     ) t1
     on t1.MenuItemCode = t2.MenuItemCode and t2.seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @KIR did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming menu items and modules don't repeat you could try something like this

```
Select case when T1.MenuItem=lag(T1.MenuItem) over (partition by T1.MenuItem order by (select null))
            then null else t1.MenuItem end MenuItem,
        case when T1.Module=lag(T1.Module) over (partition by T1.Module order by (select null)) 
             then null else t1.Module end Module,
       T2.Ingredient,T2.Quantity,T2.Price
From Table1 T1
     join Table2 T2 on T1.MenuItemCode=T2.MenuItemCode;
```